# Sembast best way to remove all documents

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm using Sembast in a Flutter app. I have to refresh all the data in a store and need a way to removeall documents in a store. I looked at the API and only way I can see is either to get all keys and use them in a finder to delete them or drop the store and recreate it. Not sure if I overlooked something to support this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delete https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast/StoreRef/delete.html method can (and should) be used. Maybe there should be a clear method that simply calls delete without filtering, it would be similar to the indexed db API...

Some info here: https://github.com/tekartik/sembast.dart/blob/master/sembast/doc/writes.md#delete-records

Answer (score 6):

This works for me -:

```
db.close();
await databaseFactoryIo.deleteDatabase(_database.path);
db = null;
```

Comment: Need to "await" the db close statement; it's a future.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
var receiptStore = intMapStoreFactory.store("receipts");
final database = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(dbPath, version: 2,
    onVersionChanged: (Database db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) async {
  if (oldVersion == 1) {
    await receiptStore.delete(db);
  }
});
```

so that I 'upgrade' the DB by deleting it.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the sembast [`deleteAll`](https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast/StoreExecutor/deleteAll.html) method to delete all records in a `Database`, which returns the list of keys that have been deleted that you can use in whatever code you need to recreate the store.

If you do not need to recreate the store you can use the sembast [`clear`](https://pub.dev/documentation/sembast/latest/sembast/StoreExecutor/clear.html) method to delete all records in the store.